# Resharper Find With Pattern - help finding constructors in multiple classes

Tags: c#, resharper

Goal:

In all classes in a particular project, find all constructors which look like this:

```
public Alert(DBConnection dbConnection, SqlInt32 Alert_ID)
    : base (dbConnection, Alert_ID)
{
}
```

and replace with this:

```
public Alert(DBConnection dbConnection, SqlInt32 Alert_ID)
    : base (dbConnection, Alert_ID)
{
}

protected Alert() {}

protected override Generated.Alert GetNew()
{
    return new Alert();
}
```

I've tried every pattern I can think of in Resharper's Find with Pattern option, but even the simplest expression like: `public Alert(DBConnection dbConnection, SqlInt32 Alert_ID)` yields "Nothing found".

Is Resharper incapable of identifying methods/constructors?  Can it only find code within them?

---

Ok - update - this pattern found the matches I want:

```
public $t$(DBConnection dbConnection) : base(dbConnection)
{
$stmt$
}
```

So next goal is to insert new methods - like a new public empty constructor.

Trying this replace pattern - but again, no joy:

```
public $t$(DBConnection dbConnection) : base(dbConnection)
{
$stmt$
}

public $t$() {}
```

if I try something like

public $t$(DBConnection dbConnection) : base(dbConnection)
    {
    $stmt$
    //hi
    }

it works- the comment is inserted.  But if I add code outside of the declared search pattern, no such luck...

So now what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following just worked for me:

```
public WCFTest1Tests()
{
$code$
}
```

Where $code$ is set to any number of statements.

Comment: Aha!  adding a statement variable into the pattern seems to have worked!  Let me just confirm this on a broader scope... seems silly that resharper can't recognize {} and {$code$} w/ no lower limit as similar but hey, it be what it is

Comment: Ok that definitely helped, but now the replace I'm seeking isn't working... updating question.